# Android Fabric events (Answer)

Tags: android, events, logging, google-fabric

I implemented Fabric answers component (kit) with the Fabric Android Studio plugin, and wrote a CustomEvent sender. I enabled debugging which says:

```
D/Answers: Logged custom event: {eventName:"ASSA", customAttributes:{"isEndpointSetUpComplete_true":" - success: true"}}
D/Answers: Sending 1 analytics files to https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events
D/Answers: Response code for analytics file send is 200
```

But on the Fabric.io page, it still says "Waiting for event". Already uninstalled/reinstalled the app many times. Is it intended and I have to wait 24 hours or something?

Comment: The first event usually takes a while to show up. I've had to wait for hours before.

Comment: I waited 28 hours and moved on. Now using Yahoo's Flurry Analytics.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Your delay sounds very unusual. It sounds like you've moved on, but if you want to dig back in, please ping me. In general, events are sent in real-time when the app is foregrounded, background or changes activities.

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell, I'm facing this exact same issue in Android. Am using Crashlytics in both iOS and Android and all is live (when it comes to crashes). but i implemented Answers today for SignUp, i tried on simulator and real devices, and still seeing the (Listening for your first event…). Any suggestions?

Comment: Try enabling debug mode and make sure you see the event logged - https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html?highlight=debug